# TV connected to PC via HDMI stopped working

Tags: windows-7, graphics-card, hdmi, tv

I have a PC connected to a Sony Bravia TV via HDMI. It worked fine for more than a year until it started to lose signal from time to time. And then one day it stopped working at all. I don't think it's a software issue since not even the motherboard's splash screen appears.

The PC is: MSI FM2-A55M-E33 / AMD A4-4000 / Radeon HD 7480D onboard graphics.

Here is the troubleshooting I did:

1. Switched ports on my TV but none worked.
2. Tried multiple cables but none worked.
3. Tried VGA cable and it worked.
4. Connected the TV to another PC (ASUS M4N68T-M LE V2 / AMD Athlon II X2 250 / nVidia GT 240 dedicated graphics) and it worked.
5. Installed the GT 240 onto the first PC and tried again: it worked. Returned GT 240 back to the ASUS.
6. Concluded that the motherboard's HDMI port was damaged.
7. Bought new motherboard MSI A68HM-E33 V2 and replaced old MSI: HDMI still didn't work.
8. Got fed up and replaced the MSI PC for the ASUS PC, keeping the hard drive. So now the TV is connected to the GT 240. After installing the drivers tested again: the two ports on the side of the TV didn't work but the two ports on the back worked.
9. Half an hour later booted PC and none of the ports were working.

I can't seem to find where the problem really is. Maybe it's the TV? I am running out of ideas.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you checked how the HDMI cable is resting in the HDMI port of the computer? Perhaps the IO plate is touching the metal shielding of the HDMI cable and somehow is causing an issue.

Comment: Also, if you have other devices connected via HDMI (especially Sony BRAVIA Sync supporting equipment) disconnect it. It might be causing problems. Also, disable Sony Bravia Sync in the TVs settings if you don't have any equipment that uses that feature. Finally, I know this goes without saying but... Make sure that you have selected to correct input using the [Input]->[Home] button on the TVs remote.

Comment: I checked what you said but no luck. I noticed that if a switch ports sometimes it starts working again, but when I restart the PC it doesn't anymore and I have to switch ports again. The last time I switched and restarted it stayed working, but I don't for how long it will.